# Iterate JSON array object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm querying out and getting a json string returned, for the sake of this example I'll post an example. I'm trying to figure out how I would go about digging through the array of values and find which is marked as default.

Example JSON

```
{
    "id": "333706819617",
    "guid": "4aCdriCG0WvfYEUkFf8_xqQEFxgwgNU8",
    "title": "Test entry",
    "author": "",
    "description": "Desc",
    "added": 1411702963000,
    "content": [
        {
            "audioChannels": 2,
            "audioSampleRate": 44100,
            "bitrate": 281656,
            "checksums": {
                "md5": "70DF3E21131F9F02C3F0A74F3664AB73"
            },
            "contentType": "audio",
            "duration": 43.258,
            "expression": "full",
            "fileSize": 1522986,
            "frameRate": 0.0,
            "format": "AAC",
            "height": 288,
            "isDefault": false,
            "language": "en",
            "sourceTime": 0.0,
            "url": "http://example.com/dZiASoxchRyS",
            "width": 352
        },
        {
            "audioChannels": 2,
            "audioSampleRate": 44100,
            "bitrate": 160000,
            "checksums": {
                "md5": "3AC622D31B9DED37792CC7FF2F086BE6"
            },
            "contentType": "audio",
            "duration": 43.206,
            "expression": "full",
            "fileSize": 866504,
            "frameRate": 0.0,
            "format": "MP3",
            "height": 0,
            "isDefault": false,
            "language": "",
            "sourceTime": 0.0,
            "url": "http://example.com/59M_PSFgGGXE",
            "width": 0
        }
    ],
    "thumbnails": [
        {
            "audioChannels": 0,
            "audioSampleRate": 0,
            "bitrate": 0,
            "checksums": {
                "md5": "BE8C98A07B3FE9020BFA464C42112999"
            },
            "contentType": "image",
            "duration": 0.0,
            "expression": "full",
            "fileSize": 20379,
            "frameRate": 0.0,
            "format": "JPEG",
            "height": 256,
            "isDefault": true,
            "language": "",
            "sourceTime": 0.0,
            "url": "http://img.example.com/waveform.jpg",
            "width": 256
        }
    ]
}
```

I take the JSON string and convert it back into a `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject mediaObject = new Gson().fromJson(mediaString, JSONObject.class);
String content = mediaObject.optString("content");
```

When I output `content` it returns the following.

```
{values=[{nameValuePairs={audioChannels=2.0, audioSampleRate=44100.0, bitrate=281656.0, checksums={nameValuePairs={md5=70DF3E21131F9F02C3F0A74F3664AB73}}......
```

How do I correctly step through the values of content and find the value of `isDefault`? In the example JSON there is no content where `isDefault = true` so it would default to the first object.

Seems I can only target the values as string, do I have to cast `content` as a `JSONArray`?

**Edit:** I can't seem to convert `mediaObject.content` into a JSONArray. `mediaObject.optJSONArray("content")` returns null. I've also tried getting it as a string then converting into a JSONArray with no prevail.

**Edit 2:** Found what the issue with the data was, when I was parsing the json with gson, it was messing with the final outputted data.

So I changed from `new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);` to `jsonObject.toString())` and I could now target the arrays using `optJSONArray`. To get them data back into a JSONObject, I used `JSONObject mediaObject = new JSONObject(mediaString);`

**GSON was altering the data**

Comment: There is an issue when trying to target the `content` when converting to string and logging it shows illformed json. The output is shown above, random keys are appearing like `value=` which I believe is messing with the system? I can't even target the `values` because it's a bad json string.

Comment: Have you looked into using regular expression?

Comment: Regular expression wouldn't of been much help, thankfully I was able to solve it with the two answer below. GSON was modifying the data when it creates a json string, so I ditched it all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of pulling the string value of content out of your JSONObject, you can get a JSONArray instead

```
JSONArray content = mediaObject.getJSONArray("content");
```

Now you can loop through the objects in your array with a pretty conventional for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject mediaItem = content.getJSONObject(i);
    boolean itemIsDefault = mediaItem.getBoolean("isDefault");
}
```

Here are the links to all the [JSONObject methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: I tried this earlier and got the error `Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException`. Is there a way that doesn't throw null if it doesn't exist? In this case `content` **always** exists

Comment: You need to check `if(jsonObj.has("key_like_isDefault"))` and then try to pull your required values

Comment: Do you mean doesn't throw `null` or doesn't throw an exception? If it's the latter, you can use `mediaObject.optJSONArray("content")`

Comment: Interesting, the loop throws `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference`

Comment: While this is partially right, the reason it wasn't working was due to `gson` converting. It was changing the json string as shown in the question. So when I went to convert it back into an `JSONObject` it wasn't playing ball.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just

```
JSONObject mJson = new JSONObject(inputString);
```

why are you using Gson?

Comment: No issue with how the json is produced, it's just an error targeting the data inside. I can't target arrays, it returns null.